# newtxtext stopped working after update

Tags: newtx

I just updated miktex and realized that `newtxtext` stopped working, although `newtxmath` is working well with libertine or other fonts using pdflatex. What should I do to make `newtxtext` work again?

### Here is what I get:

Log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.2.2) 3 MAR 2015 02:08
entering extended mode
**tA-poblem.tex
(tA-poblem.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsart.cls"
Document Class: amsart 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
\linespacing=\dimen102
\normalparindent=\dimen103
\normaltopskip=\skip41
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip42
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen104
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count79
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count80
\leftroot@=\count81
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count82
\DOTSCASE@=\count83
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count84
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count85
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count86
\dspbrk@lvl=\count87
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count88
\column@=\count89
\maxfields@=\count90
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip43
\multlinetaggap=\skip44
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 388.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert233
\abstractbox=\box28
\listisep=\skip45
\c@part=\count91
\c@section=\count92
\c@subsection=\count93
\c@subsubsection=\count94
\c@paragraph=\count95
\c@subparagraph=\count96
\c@figure=\count97
\c@table=\count98
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\captionindent=\dimen113
\thm@style=\toks19
\thm@bodyfont=\toks20
\thm@headfont=\toks21
\thm@notefont=\toks22
\thm@headpunct=\toks23
\thm@preskip=\skip48
\thm@postskip=\skip49
\thm@headsep=\skip50
\dth@everypar=\toks24
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count99
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks25
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen114
\Gin@req@width=\dimen115
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
Package: color 2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 137.
)
(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mh\mathtools.sty
Package: mathtools 2013/02/12 v1.13 mathematical typesetting tools
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty"
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count100
\calc@Bcount=\count101
\calc@Adimen=\dimen116
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen117
\calc@Askip=\skip51
\calc@Bskip=\skip52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 75.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 76.
\calc@Ccount=\count102
\calc@Cskip=\skip53
)
(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mh\mhsetup.sty
Package: mhsetup 2010/01/21 v1.2a programming setup (MH)
)
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\['isalreadyrobust on input line 129.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\]'isalreadyrobust on input line 129.
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count103
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen118
\origjot=\skip54
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen119
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen120
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen121
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen122
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen123
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen124
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count104
\Gm@cntv=\count105
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count106
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen125
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen126
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen127
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen128
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen129
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen130
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen131
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen132
\Gm@dimlist=\toks26
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\newtxtext.sty"
Package: newtxtext 2015/02/27 v1.411
`newtxtext' v1.411, 2015/02/27 Text macros taking advantage of TeX-Gyre Termes
fonts (msharpe)
(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fontaxes\fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
)
\ntx@fs=\dimen133
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks27
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks28
)
\XKV@depth=\count107
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count108
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count109
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp) 5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp) 4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp) 3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp) 2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp) 1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp) 0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp) Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp) only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp) Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp) See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 71.
Package textcomp Info: Changing ? sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 72.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 266.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 281.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 282.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 283.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 284.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 285.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 286.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 287.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 288.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 289.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 290.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 291.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 292.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 293.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 294.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 295.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 296.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 297.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 298.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 299.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 300.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 301.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 302.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 303.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 304.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 305.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 306.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 307.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 308.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 309.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 310.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 311.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 312.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 313.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 314.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 315.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 316.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 317.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 318.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 319.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 320.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 321.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 322.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 323.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 324.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 325.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 326.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 327.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 328.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 329.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 330.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 331.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 332.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 333.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 335.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 336.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 337.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 338.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 339.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 340.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mtpro2\mtpro2.sty"
Package: mtpro2 2009/4/27 v2.3 MathTimePro II - added arc accents MathTimePro I
I - fixed rbrace problem with straightbraces and morphedbraces options MathTime
Pro II - fix bug with z = \delimiter "026E30F widetilde{\delimiter "026E30F sum
_{x }}MathTimePro II v2 font support (PCTeX/WaS)MathTimePro II v2.1a Allowed al
ternate form of I in Math Script Fonts (MS)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\t1ntxtlf.fd"
File: t1ntxtlf.fd 2015/01/17 v1.0 font definition file for T1/ntx/tlf
)
\pointcount@=\count110
\prePbox@=\box29
\Pbox@=\box30
\LRbox@=\box31
\HATbox@=\box32
\TDbox@=\box33
\CHbox@=\box34
\ARCbox@=\box35
\preSbox@=\box36
\Sbox@=\box37
\SQcount@=\count111
\SQRTbox@=\box38
\UPROOT@=\count112
\LEFTROOT@=\count113
\limtype@=\count114
\xlfont@=\count115
\xlposition@=\count116
\xlposition@ii=\count117
\optype@=\count118
\x@count=\count119
\maxXLscripts@=\dimen134
)
(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mathalfa\mathalfa.sty
Package: mathalfa 2012/07/10 - 1.07mathalfa (License LPPL) Michael Sharpe
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\bm.sty"
Package: bm 2014/10/28 v1.1c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 203.
)
\c@theorem=\count120
\c@lemma=\count121
\c@corollary=\count122
\c@remark=\count123
\c@example=\count124
\c@claim=\count125
(tA-poblem.aux)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
(C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count126
\scratchdimen=\dimen135
\scratchbox=\box39
\nofMPsegments=\count127
\nofMParguments=\count128
\everyMPshowfont=\toks29
\MPscratchCnt=\count129
\MPscratchDim=\dimen136
\MPnumerator=\count130
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count131
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks30
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* hratio: 1:1
* vratio: 1:1
* modes: twoside
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(90.3375pt, 433.62pt, 90.33751pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(90.3375pt, 614.295pt, 90.3375pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=433.62pt
* \textheight=614.295pt
* \oddsidemargin=18.0675pt
* \evensidemargin=18.06752pt
* \topmargin=-3.9325pt
* \headheight=8.0pt
* \headsep=14.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=12.0pt
* \marginparwidth=90.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=7.0pt plus 11.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
\c@mv@tabular=\count132
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count133
[1{C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2]
Overfull \hbox (3.35092pt too wide) detected at line 142
\LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 X[].t/ \LMP2/mtt/m/n/12 D \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 t[] [] ; X[].t/
\LMP2/mtt/m/n/12 D \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 t[] [] :
[]
[3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8]
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\t1ntxtt.fd"
File: t1ntxtt.fd 2012/04/20 v3.1
) [9]
(tA-poblem.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5497 strings out of 493698
73526 string characters out of 3141998
154035 words of memory out of 3000000
8578 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
105814 words of font info for 69 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1186 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
34i,10n,40p,887b,308s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ntx-Regular-tlf-t1): Font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 at 4
80 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by not working? Is there an error message that you can share with us? Or better yet, can you put together a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Run on the command line the command `updmap`. This will update the pdftex.map.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer (+1) This is, in fact, an answer, why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Run on the command line the command updmap. This will update the pdftex.map.